# What methods are able to capture the properties of paramagnetic materials?

Tags: density-functional-theory, dynamical-mean-field-theory

In DFT calculations one isn't able to set up a system which has no magnetic ordering but has local magnetic moments that are non-zero. [This](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4162/how-can-i-properly-represent-paramagnetic-materials-in-dft-calculations) answer talks about how one can try to use a very large supercell where the magnetic ions' magnetic moments are initialized randomly, and I've also seen several papers which go the opposite direction and just turn the spin off in the calculation so that there are no unpaired electrons.

I know that DMFT calculations are able to capture the properties of systems with local magnetic moments that are not ordered, but I was wondering if there are other approaches that are able to work, even if they aren't commonly used or it hasn't been implemented so that it works. For example, is it possible in approaches based on Hedin's equations, FCI, Monte Carlo methods, etc. to get paramagnetic behavior? I would guess that many methods are limited by having periodic boundary conditions that assume that the magnetic moment of an ion in one cell is the same as the magnetic moment in another cell, but it would be a bit surprising to me if DMFT were the only method that could handle paramagnetism without having randomly distributed magnetic moments in extremely large supercells.

Comment: +1. I wonder if you could be more specific instead of just saying "the properties". Can you say which properties?

Comment: I had a tough time thinking of how best to say that. I think the main thing is just whether the method is capable of producing a solution which has no magnetic ordering, but has localized magnetic moments. I have seen this written mathematically as a system with <S_z> = 0, but <S_z^2> non zero. There are examples of materials where their lattice constants or band gap depend on magnetic ordering, and this dependence motivates part of my question, but primarily I’m trying to ask if there are methods besides DMFT where paramagnetic solutions are possible

Comment: So you want to know whether there's a method that can calculate $\langle S_z \rangle$ and $\langle S_z^2 \rangle$ for a material, ensuring that the first one is 0 and the second one is non-zero?

Comment: ＠AGS Sorry, if I misunderstand you, but there is nothing special about paramagnetic ions in a lattice from DFT point of view. In a paramagnetic material, there is no long range ordering, but it doesn’t mean that in an atomistic simulation the $<S_z>$ must be a static zero at unit cell level, that is a thermal average.

Comment: for collinear calculation you can use SQS structure of binary system. Put A as upspin and B as low spin and constrain net spin over cell to be zero

Comment: I think the focus on the expectation value of S_z is missing the point. That’s an example of one way that a paramagnetic system could be different from a system with no spin, but the actual thing that I care about is if you can have a paramagnetic system. I agree that what I said about the expectation value of Sz is imprecise. The comment which suggests using AFM ordering also gets at why what I said isn’t a good way to think about it. In any case, what I’m actually trying to ask is just are there electronic structure methods besides DMFT that can yield a paramagnetic result

Comment: @AGS DFT calculations generally do not give you thermal average of a system. Expectation value of S is a thermal average in this case, i.e. in different times you would observe all those spin arrangements, that you can simulate with DFT, one by one. Depending what properties you are interested in, the an AF or broken-symmetry state plus F can be well enough states for the thermal averaging.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. My question though is are there other methods besides DMFT that can do finite temperature calculations which have fluctuating magnetic moments. Perhaps I didn’t make this clear enough, but what I’m after isn’t a practical way to try to do the best I can for a specific system, but instead I’m interested in if there are theoretical methods that can work.

Comment: Your comments have been helpful in pointing out that in the original way I framed the question I was misguided in ignoring the fact that thermal effects and fluctuations of the spin are the fundamental thing that is difficult to capture in electronic structure methods, and the issue isn’t merely something to do with the ion magnetic moment being duplicated in periodic images. In fact, (if I understand correctly) in a DMFT calculation one can get a paramagnetic result at a certain temperature even with one ion in the unit cell because the magnetic moment is able to fluctuate

Comment: AGS, have you made any progress on this? Please update us! @Greg might not have seen your comments since you didn't use the @ ping feature. Apologies to Greg for the ping just now if you did see these comments before!

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks, Nike, but I still do not understand OP’s problem and I do not think I can add anything helpful.

Comment: @Greg I'll vote to close due to needing more details/clarity.